# Getting jQuery Toggle to close once thumb is clicked

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

Really need to get this fixed, I'm trying to make it so if you click on one of the smaller thumbnails the image collection toggle will close, I've managed to make it close if you click the toggle im having trouble with this, please see link if needed http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/fullthrottle/

Thank you for any help : )

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".dropgallery a, #fp_thumbtoggle").removeAttr("title");

$('#fp_thumbtoggle').click(function() {
    $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");

    if ($('#fp_thumbtoggle').hasClass('active')){
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'65px'});
    }else{
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'185px'});
    }
    $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
    return false;
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
$("#fp_thumbtoggle").click();
```

to the click handler for $('.thumb'). It calls the thumb toggle click handler.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work when editing your page using firebug.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".dropgallery a, #fp_thumbtoggle").removeAttr("title");

//Notice change below
    $('#fp_thumbtoggle, .dropgallery img').click(function() {
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");

        if ($('#fp_thumbtoggle').hasClass('active')){
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'65px'});
        }else{
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'185px'});
        }
        $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
        return false;
    });

    });
```

Comment: This works but the image no longer changers. I'm also using this gallery.js http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/fullthrottle/wp-content/themes/fullthrottle/js/gallery.js would it be possible for you just to take two and have a quick look any help you be much appreciated : )